# Binding to DataTable that is a Property of another Object: System.ArgumentException Column does not belong to the table

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a winform application and using data binding to display information about a collection of objects. I've successfully retrieved Strings and Lists from the object and displayed them on my form. I'm running into trouble displaying the object's DataTable.

The object has a `DataTable` property:
`public DataTable Table { get; set; }` 
The table will be populated by reading a file, but for debugging right now I'm manually creating and populating the table like so:

```
  private void CreateDataTable()
        {
            Table = new DataTable();
            Table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            Table.Columns.Add("FuelKg", typeof(int));
            Table.Columns.Add("Model", typeof(string));

            Table.Rows.Add(1, 800, "Boeing 747");
            Table.Rows.Add(2, 1023, "Airbus A380");
            Table.Rows.Add(3, 62, "Cessna 162");

        }
```

I use data binding to bind the DataTable to my DataGridView:

```
BindingSource bsAirplanes = new BindingSource();
BindingSource bsTable = new BindingSource();
//...additional code...

//databinding for datatable
bsTable.DataSource = bsAirplanes;
bsTable.DataMember = "Table";
dataGridView2.DataSource = bsTable;
dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

When I load the form on the first record everything looks great.
[image]
However, when I move to any other record, the DataGridView that's bound to my DataTable does not populate. For each column in my datatable, I get an error stating:

```
System.ArgumentException: Column 'ID' does not belong to the table .
  at System.Data.DataRow.CheckColumn(DataColumn column)
  at System.Data.DataRow.get_Item(DataColumn column, DataRowVersion version)
  at System.Data.DataRowView.GetColumnValue(DataColumn column)
  at System.Data.DataColumnPropertyDescriptor.GetValue(Object component)
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.GetValue(Int32 boundColumnIndex, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex)
```

The DataGridView is now empty except for the column names.
[image]

I know that the columns do indeed belong to my table because I've manually stepped through the code and can see them in my DataTable object. **It seems like there is some issue refreshing the data when I move to the next record. Perhaps the DataGridView is only bound to the DataTable in my FIRST Airplane object?**

Answer (score 0):

After many rounds of trial and error, I devised this solution. I am not sure it's the best solution, but it works. If there is a better way I'd love to know!

My suspicion that the bsTable BindingSource was linked only to the first object's DataTable seems to be correct. I need to manually update the bsTable's DataSource when I change the main object.

I added an event listener to my main DataGridView (bound to bsAirplanes). When the user selects a different row in the grid, the secondary DataGridView (bound to bsTable) is re-bound to the **current** Airplane's DataTable and the correct data populates.

In the Form1.Designer file:

```
this.dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dataGridView1_Changed);
```

In the Form.cs file:

```
 private void dataGridView1_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bsTable.DataSource = bsAirplanes.Current; //notice I am using bsAirplanes.Current, not bsAirplanes
            bsTable.DataMember = "Table";
            dataGridView2.DataSource = bsTable;
            dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved an error similar to this error by clearing and reseting the BindingSource before re-assigning its DataSource property like the following:

```
bsTable.DataSource = null;
bsTable.ResetBindings(true);
// ...
// recreate or reload myDataTable

// if I did not clear and reset the BindingSource, 
//    the following line throws the DataGridView.DataError
bsTable.DataSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;
```